# How HTTP is related to REST?

Tags: rest, http

I'm really confused about how REST is related to HTTP since I'm new to web developing and still learning about it.  This my understanding about my question, http is related to rest because it meets the principle of rest. Please enlightened me.

Comment: You use HTTP/HTTPS to call the REST API.

Comment: If you are asking about HTTP APIs, see [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html)

Comment: Another useful [link](https://www.educative.io/blog/what-are-rest-apis)

Answer (score 1):

> How HTTP is related to REST?

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is the [architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/software_arch.htm#sec_1_5) defined to guide the development of the [HTTP/1.1 standard in the 1990s](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2068).

More carefully:

- REST is the architectural style
- the World Wide Web is an application whose architecture conforms to the constraints of that style (mostly, see [chapter 6 of Fielding's disseration](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm))
- HTTP is the "primary application-level protocol" in the Web architecture.